# setLayerType substitute for Android 2.3.3?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

How can I make my Android app compatible with previous Android versions if I use API from the view class like setLayerType that are not on the Android 2.3.3 API? What can I substitute this method with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
     // only for gingerbread and newer versions
//        setLayerType
}
```

or through reflection

```
try {
    Method setLayerTypeMethod = mWebView.getClass().getMethod("setLayerType", new Class[] {int.class, Paint.class});
    if (setLayerTypeMethod != null)
         setLayerTypeMethod.invoke(yourView, new Object[] {LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null});
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();   
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but do these solutions effectively replace the functionality setLayerType had, so that we essentially have an equivalent of that function for 2.3.3? Because it seems like the first solution just gets rid of the function of Gingerbread is detected.

Comment: you can not have that functionality on ginberbread . it has been introduced since HoneyComb

Comment: As blackbelt pointed out, change GINGERBREAD to HONEYCOMB and the > to >=

Answer (score 0):

to disable hardware acceleraton you can use android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

more detail here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html#controlling

but pay attention with android:hardwareAccelerated="false" because you will pay the cost with app performance

i think the best deal is to use reflection as described by blackbelt

Comment: Thats why he is using setLayerType instead including the all aplication